# expanding variables inside {..} in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, list, variables

I have the following shell script

```
cat test.sh    

j=00000001;
k=00000005;
l=$(echo {00000001..00000005}.jpg);
m=$(echo {$j..$k}.jpg);
ls $l
ls $m
```

Here is the output

```
 ./test.sh 
00000001.jpg  00000002.jpg  00000003.jpg  00000004.jpg  00000005.jpg
ls: cannot access {00000001..00000005}.jpg: No such file or directory
```

My doubt is "Why is the ls $m not working".
and How to make that work?

Thanks in advance.
lin

Comment: Use */usr/bin/seq* with variable ranges.

Comment: I have used seq to obtain the list                           `j=00000001;
k=00000025;
m=$(seq -w  $j $k);
echo $m`                                                           But do i have a way of attaching .jpg after each element in the list other than using a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequence expansion only happens for literal numbers.  Variable expansion occurs after sequence expansion:

> A  sequence  expression takes the form {x..y}, where **x and y are either
> integers or single characters.**  When integers are supplied, the expression
> expands  to each number between x and y, inclusive.  When characters are
> supplied, the expression expands  to  each  character  lexicographically
> between x and y, inclusive.  Note that both x and y must be of the same type.
>
> **Brace expansion is performed before any other expansions**, and any characters
> special to other expansions are preserved in the result.  It is strictly textual.
> Bash does not apply any syntactic interpretation to the context of the expansion
> or the text between the braces.

For your case, you can use eval:

```
m=`eval echo {$j..$k}.jpg`
```

Comment: Thanks,that clarifies it.now i need to think of other ways to implement what i need.My requirement is to process a small sequential subset of numbered jpg files from a large set of jpg files and incrementing the subset after each processing.

Comment: You can use eval: m=`eval echo {$j..$k}.jpg`

Comment: i cannot find a `man eval` in my bash.But the command is there and it worked.

Comment: @xenoxen since its a shell builtin, you should run `help eval` or search `man bash` for `eval `